# array.map needs index but doesn't need currentValue

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an empty array that I want to fill with strings. The strings will use an `index` value to count up. For instance:

```
'item 1'
'item 2'
'item 3'
```

I have a working `map` function that will do this:

```
let items  = new Array(100).fill().map((item, index) => {
 return `item ${index + 1}` 
})
```

While this does fill the array with strings that iterate up through the index value, I am also passing in the `item` argument to the `map` function, which is the `currentValue` (as named in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)). I'm not actually using this value, though.

Seeing as how this value *has* to be passed in, I tried passing in `null`, but that gave me an error. I also tried to pass in an empty object, as in `.map(( {}, index) => ...)}`. honestly, I don't know what the rationale is to the empty object, but I figured I'd try it. Needless to say, that didn't work.

My question is -- **what do you do if you have no use for a required argument like this?** Can I pass some kind of undefined or useless value in there? Should I be using another function other than `map` to do this?

I could do this with a `for` loop:

```
let items = new Array(100).fill()

for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++ {
    items[index] = `item ${index + 1}`
}
```

Would the `for` loop be the better choice in this case?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about it. Name the argument something like `_` if you want to be clear that you aren't using it. If you are going to use a `for` loop, you don't need to initialize the array. `let items = []` is fine.

Comment: Your current working `.map` function looks fine, just replace `item` with `_`. You could also use `Array.from` instead of `new Array` followed by `fill`

Comment: You're not "passing in" anything to the function. The `map` method is passing things in and you are just giving names to them. And yeah, like Mark Meyer said, don't worry about it. What's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can create a "range" array so that you map over numbers directly: `[...Array(10).keys()].map(i => \`item ${i + 1}\`)`

Comment: If performance is an issue then the for loop may be more performant since you drop the overhead of pushing callbacks onto the callstack. Otherwise, just give it a name or underscore and move on as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill` + `map` is a waste when you can just use `from` -

```js
const result =
  Array.from(Array(10), (_,i) => `item ${i + 1}`)
  
console.log(result)
// [ "item 1"
// , "item 2"
// , "item 3"
// , "item 4"
// , "item 5"
// , "item 6"
// , "item 7"
// , "item 8"
// , "item 9"
// , "item 10"
// ]
```

Comment: As long as you're preventing waste you can get rid of the throw-away interior array and pass an object `{length: 10}`.

Comment: `(_,i) => \`item ${i + 1}\`` is a map too.

Answer (score 1):

Referring your code

```
let items  = new Array(100).fill().map((item, index) => {
 return `item ${index + 1}` 
})
```

item will be "undefined" and yes, you need to pass item(currentValue) as it's a required field.

In a single line it can be achieved:

```
let items  = Array.from(Array(100).keys()).map( item => `item ${item+1}`);
```

without map

```
let items  = Array.from(Array(100).keys(), item => `item ${item+1}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

An unused argument should be assigned to `_`:

```
let items = new Array(100).fill().map((_, index) => `item ${index + 1}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the unused argument. If you really mind, try the following code:

```js
var items  = new Array(...new Array(100).keys()).map(index => {
 return `item ${index + 1}` 
});
console.log(items);
```